# Iterate through multiple linked lists at the same time in c++ +linked list

Tags: c++, list

I am doing a task that requires to calculate a metric from a linked list that contains multiple linked lists of char (each row is a single linked list as shown in the graph). So I will need to iterate through every node that contains a space from the second row, to check how many spaces are surrounding by four other spaces (top, bottom, left, right). For instance, referring to the graph below, the second space in the third row is surrounding by four spaces, so count++. (the "H" just simply means non-space character, sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post a real picture).

I am allowed to used the STL  linked list library. I was trying to use three iterators to iterate through three rows at the same time. However, the code gets really messy and does not even work correctly as each row has different lengths. I have been thinking the solution for two days, but as I've been practicing C++ for only two months, so what I could think of is pretty limited. So I am wondering if anyone could give me a hint or a smarter solution, please.

space | space | --H -- | --H -- | -- H -- | NULL| NULL

--- H --| --H ---| space | space | --- H- | -- H -- | NULL

--- H --| space | space | space | -- H-- | space| NULL

space | --H -- | space | space | -- H -- | NULL | NULL

Comment: You can keep std::list, std::array or std::vector of iterators.

Comment: just for clarity, you're using a `std::list<std::list<char>>`; is that correct? Code would speak *much* clearer of what you're actually doing than trying to post paragraphs of descriptions. Don't try to tell us *about* the code unless you also plan on *posting* it. Only then can we potentially see glaring artifacts of ill-taken-paths.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help: (in C++11): [Live example](https://ideone.com/1ha7tx).

```
std::size_t countSpaceSurroundBySpace(const std::list<std::list<char>>& l)
{
    if (l.size() < 3u) {
        return 0u;
    }
    auto it1 = l.begin();
    auto it2 = std::next(it1);
    auto it3 = std::next(it2);
    std::size_t count = 0u;

    for (; it3 != l.end(); ++it1, ++it2, ++it3) {
        // pointers on the 5 characters
        std::list<char>::const_iterator its[5] = {
            it1->begin(),
            it2->begin(),
            it2->begin(),
            it2->begin(),
            it3->begin()
        };
        if (its[0] == it1->end()) { continue; }
        ++its[0];
        if (its[2] == it2->end()) { continue; }
        ++its[2];
        ++its[3];
        if (its[3] == it2->end()) { continue; }
        ++its[3];
        if (its[4] == it3->end()) { continue; }
        ++its[4];
        for (; its[0] != it1->end() && its[3] != it2->end() && its[4] != it3->end();) {
            if (std::all_of(std::begin(its), std::end(its), [](std::list<char>::const_iterator it) { return *it == ' '; })) {
                ++count;
            }
            for (auto& it : its) {
                ++it;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `std::vector` of `std::list::iterator`s. You'd have an inner loop that just does whatever computation you want at each step, if the `iterator` isn't already at the corresponding `list`'s `end()`.  This will be a lot easier if your incoming `list`s are in turn provided as an array or a `vector`.