# C++ iterators with linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I have a linked list of objects where each object has a linked list of `char`.

I declared three iterators:

```
top = someList.begin();

middle = top++;

bottom = middle++;
```

When I print the list of each of those iterators, it doesn't match up with what the full list looks like.

Basically by the end of those declaration statements top becomes the middle row, middle is what its meant to be and bottom becomes what the top row is meant to be.

I am assuming it's the way I declare the iterators with the increments. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You're gonna need to post more code before people can properly help you. Something compilable would be nice.

Comment: Maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440462/iterate-through-multiple-linked-lists-at-the-same-time-in-c-linked-list

Comment: Do you really mean `top++` and not `top+1`? Similarly `middle++` and not `middle+1`?

Comment: @theharshest: you mean `middle = std::next(top)`.

Comment: The postfix++ operator increments the iterator and returns the original value.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @theharshest yes i do mean "++" i have tried "+1" but i receive a compile error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see what happens after each statement. assume position marks `0,1,2,3`... for the list
The problem is in the post ++

```
top = someList.begin();
//top=0

middle = top++;
//middle=0
//top=1

bottom = middle++;
//bottom=0
//middle=1
//top=1
```

Comment: I see what is happening. thank you for breaking that down for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, based on your description here:

> basically by the end of those declaration statements top becomes the
>   middle row, middle is what its meant to be and bottom becomes what the
>   top row is meant to be.

When you assign `middle = top++`, you are assigning `middle` to the old value of `top`, and simultaneously incrementing `top`. It is the same idea in the second assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
#include <iterator>

//...
top = someList.begin();

middle = std::next( top );

bottom = std::next( middle );
```

Or you could write the same without using function `std::next`

```
top = someList.begin();

++( middle = top );

++( bottom = middle );
```

Or more readable

```
top = someList.begin();

middle = top;
++middle;

bottom = middle;
++bottom;
```

Or you could use function `std::advance`

```
#include <iterator>

//...
top = someList.begin();

middle = someList.begin();
std::advance( middle, 1 );

bottom = someList.begin();
std::advance( bottom, 2 );
```